# What is the difference between span and period in this context?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context, differences

1. [span](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/span) the period of time that sometimes exists or happens
2. [period](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/period) a length of time

That said, I still don't see the difference. I have the following exercise in my schoolbook:

> The course would have been of more benefit if it had been for a longer
>   ***period***/interval/span.

The corrects answer is ***period***. However, how would you explain it to a student?

Comment: In most contexts *period* implies repetition.

Comment: The _period_ of a pendulum is the time it takes to swing back and forth once. The _interval_ of a ticking clock is the time between each 'tick' - which is usually one second.The average _span_ of a lifetime is usually about seventy years or so.

Comment: I don’t think your college will find it easy to justify any form of “been for a longer period/interval/span”. If those are your choices, you're stuck with "period"… still a dreadful sentence.

Part of the problem is that you’re working with one definition of each of two rater similar words.

"The course would have been of more benefit if it had been for a longer period/interval/span" should rather be, for instance “The course would have been of more benefit if it had lasted/run (for) longer”

If that needed a measure, it might be “… for a longer time”.